# Calling a function from another function

Tags: php, function

I have a problem in calling a function from a function. These are the two functions:

```
function getevents() {
    $date = $this->input->post('attendanceDateadd'); 
    $Event = $this->input->post('Event'); 
    $Timing = $this->input->post('Timing'); 
    $CompanyName = $this->input->post('CompanyName'); 
    $EventDescription = $this->input->post('EventDescription');

    $res = $this->eventmodel->getevents($date,$Event,$Timing,$CompanyName,$EventDescription);

    if($res == true) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'data added successfully !');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('response','data already exsists !');
    }
    redirect('EventController/events'); 
}

function Companyname() {   
    $data['Companyname'] = $this->eventmodel->getCompanyname();
    //print_r($data['Companyname']);
    $this->load->view('addevents',$data);
}
```

I am trying to call the function Company name in previous function.  Can  anyone guide me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? i.e. which type of error to you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your functions are inside a class, so you must call your function like this:

```
$this->Companyname();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `Companyname();`.

If your code is inside a class then call it like so: `$this->Companyname();`.

Comment: Then tell us more about your problem. What have you tried so far, did you get any errors. Is the code you posted inside of a class or not. Are the functions in the same file/class, if not are both files included, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If this function is inside a class, then it should probably be

```
function Companyname() {   
    $this->data['Companyname'] = $this->eventmodel->getCompanyname();
    //print_r($data['Companyname']);
    $this->load->view('addevents',$this->data);
}
```

if not, you have to initialize `$data` before (and `$this` makes no sense anymore):

```
function Companyname() {
    $data = array();
    $data['Companyname'] = $this->eventmodel->getCompanyname();
    //print_r($data['Companyname']);
    $this->load->view('addevents',$data);
}
```

You should provide a more complete code example.

The other thing:

You wrote:

> i am tring to call the function Company name in previous function.

1. Do you mean you try to call the function `Companyname` that you define in your code, i.e. `function Companyname() {}`, and have problem with this **or**
2. Do you try to call the function/method `$this->eventmodel->getCompanyname()` inside `Companyname` and have problems with that.

If the first case applies, I cannot see where you call `Companyname` in `getevents` (am I blind??)

Comment: I'm just curious what could possibly posses a framework to not allow you to just use `$this->CompanyName()`